# Snapshooting data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

i like to snapshot data from Firebase. It only works after i sync my files from VS Code (ctrl + s). I can view the data after that process, but it is not loading the ListTile with the attributes from firestore on its own. Does somebody had a similar problem and help out? 
Thank you

```
String _userID;

Future getUserId() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    _userID = user.uid.toString();
  }

StreamBuilder buildStream(BuildContext context) {
    final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

    setState(() {
      getUserId();  
    }); 

return StreamBuilder(
  stream: databaseReference.collection("users").
                            document("$_userID").
                            collection("usersEventList").
                            snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("No event found");
    return ListView.builder(
      itemExtent: 80.0,
      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
        buildCanbanList(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
    );
  },
);
}
```

Before sync / After sync:

[image: before sync] [image: after sync]

Comment: when i insert the UserID from firestore directly into the code, instead of using a variable, the widget displays data instantly.

Comment: Hi, Adrian. Welcome to StackOverflow! Is this your build method? All of it? The problem is probably that your _userId is being filled after the streambuilder makes the request.

Comment: Hey @George. I get your point. That is the reason why i have to "reload", because _userId is after that initialized.

Comment: buildStream() gets called inside build() at body: buildStream(context). Do you know a workaround how to initialize  _userId before Stream gets build?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use UID to acces database in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724966/how-to-use-uid-to-acces-database-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_userId needs to get declared before StreamBuilder gets build. That is the reason why i had to "reload" every time i wanted to see data.
Correct answer is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54725472/12246792