# Failed to get uid to use within DatabaseService class in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I face a problem where I can't get the current user ID from my firebase. I've already make that every new user will have their own collection based on the UID like this:

```
 void addImagetoFirestore() async {
    final CollectionReference imageData = Firestore.instance.collection(uid);
```

This is my DatabaseService class

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});
  String useruid;
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


//Collection reference
  final CollectionReference warrantyCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('user id here');

  List<Picture> _warrantyListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Picture(
          name: doc.data['product name'],
          info: doc.data['info'],
          url: doc.data['url'],
          uid: doc.data['uid']);
    }).toList();
  }

  Future updateUserData(String name) async {
    return await warrantyCollection.document(uid).setData({'name': name});
  }

  Stream<List<Picture>> get picture {
    return warrantyCollection.snapshots().map(_warrantyListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

[I've tried referring to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724966/how-to-use-uid-to-acces-database-in-flutter),
but it seem like I can't just make something like

```
final CollectionReference warrantyCollection = Firestore.instance.collection(useridmethod());
```

are there any other alternative that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting uid as a parameter to class, fetch it in constructor because in your case  `final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;` is useless as I see.

try this;

```dart
DatabaseService(){
    userId = auth.currentUser.uid;
}
```